# Index with manually-added additional data

Tags: indexing

I'm trying to make an index at the end of a thesis that includes not only the page numbers where a particular term is mentioned, but also two additional bits of information related to that term that I want to supply manually. I might want to put this all in a table for clarity, but I suspect it won't fit on a single page, and I'm alright doing it in a list form instead.

I'm envisioning a table something like this:

| language | argument-associated morphology? | clause-level morphology? | page numbers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Coptic | no? | focus concord | 2-4, 7, 19, 31 |
| Hausa | yes | extraction morphology | 3-4, 7, 17, 22 |

and so on. The first column is the key I'd like to index based on, the middle two columns are information I need to provide manually per key, and the last column is the page numbers the key is found on. Again, I'd also be okay doing this as a list, as well; perhaps something like this:

- Coptic (2-4, 7, 19, 31): no argument-associated morphology; focus concord
- Hausa (3-4, 7, 17, 22): argument-associated morphology; extraction morphology

I can build such a table or list manually using `cleveref` and `\cpageref`, but I'd have to set up a new label for every instance of each language name, and I'm not sure it would concatenate page numbers or remove duplicate page numbers properly. Beyond that, I have no idea how to accomplish this.

As a bonus, it would be nice to be able to group certain keys together (e.g. Coptic and Hausa both under a line with 'Afroasiatic' in the first column and the other three columns blank), with a couple of other headers), but alphabetised is fine as well if it saves me manually building a table.

Is there any convenient way to do this, or am I trying to do things LaTeX's indexing mechanisms aren't set up to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to do this in place of the regular index, the solution would be to do some clever work around how the `theindex` and `\item` command within it are defined. Unfortunately, the default definition doesn't make it easy to parse the arguments to `\item` very easily. I'm thinking something along the lines of

```
{\catcode`\^^M=\active
\gdef\@idxitem#1,#2^^M{%
  ... stuff goes here careful about newlines!
}%
}
```

This will put the index entry in `#1` and the page numbers in `#2`

You'll want to be able to define the extra information in the table. You could create a command like the following:

```
\newcommand{\languageinfo}[3]{%
   \@namedef{#1@argument}{#2}
   \@namedef{#1@clause}{#3}
}
```

which could be used like:

```
\languageinfo{Hausa}{yes}{extraction morphology}
```

Then are definition for `\@idxitem` above could be something like

```
#1&\@nameuse{#1@argument}&\@nameuse{#1@clause}&#2\\
```

Now we just need to redefine the `theindex` environment:

```
{\catcode`\^^M=\active
 \gdef\theindex{%
    \let^^M\relax % don't let bare newlines do anything
    \let\item\@idxitem
    \let\indexspace\relax
    \let\par\relax
    \chapter*{\indexname}
    \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\indexname}%
                    {\MakeUppercase\indexname}%
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{llll}% assuming that it fits on one line
    \textbf{language}&\textbf{argument-associated morphology?}&\textbf{clause-level morphology?}&\textbf{page numbers}\\
}}
\def\endtheindex{\end{tabular}}
```

You'll want to do something different if your index is more than one page.

If you wanted to do grouping of languages, you could take advantage of the `\subitem` and `\subsubitem` commands that are part of LaTeX's indexing when you do, e.g., `\index{Afroasiatic languages!Hausa}` **but** you will lose the easily parsed argument to `\item` and the macros become a bit more complicated. (Effectively, you'll define `\@idxitem#1^^M` and then have to parse out whether there's a comma in `#1`.)

All of the above uses `@` in macro names, so the definitions of the commands/environments should either be enclosed with `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother` or (better) put into a package, say `thesisindex.sty` and loaded with `\usepackage{thesisindex}`.

Comment: That looks quite complicated, but I think I understand most of it. I'll try it when I get a chance and come back with questions / accept your answer if it works. Thank you!

Comment: @Sjiveru Glad to see that it worked for you. I didn't actually test any of it.